# php.ini not working in IIS?

Tags: php, configuration-files

I've set `magic_quotes_gpc = Off` in `php.ini`,but I see it's still `On` in `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must be sure you modified the right `php.ini` file : there can be many files called `php.ini` -- and only one is "*the right one*".

You can see which `php.ini` file is used in the output of `phpinfo()` : there should be an entry called `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` that indicates the directory in which `php.ini` is looked for, and an entry called `Loaded Configuration File` that indicates the full path+name of the `php.ini` file that's used.

Then : don't forget to restart the webserver, so the modifications to `php.ini` are taken into account *(Not sure that's necessary with IIS, but as it's required with Apache, I suppose it cannot hurt with IIS)*

If that doesn't change a thing : what if you try to modify another directive : is the modification taken into account ?

Comment: Yes,it's from here:http://222.73.204.65:81/test.php.As for restarting,I just restarted my own site,there are many others hosted in IIS.

Comment: I restarted IIS, and it's working now.Why it doesn't work only restarting the **site**?

Comment: I suppose you found out : right now, I see `Off` for the `magic_quotes_gpc` directive, in the output of your `phpinfo()` ;-) *(edit : I didn't see your second comment before posting mine)*

Comment: I have no idea what kind of difference there is between a "site" and the whole "server" with IIS, to be honest -- sorry about that.

Comment: Restarting the site in IIS6 doesn't help. I managed to reread php.ini by recycling (or stopping/starting) Application Pool which contains target site. IIS7 is fine with just restarting target site

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can disable it from your script too:

```
// disable magic_quotes_runtime
if (get_magic_quotes_runtime())
{
 @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the php.ini file that was loaded via the [php_ini_loaded_file](http://us.php.net/php_ini_loaded_file) function. Restart your web server.

Answer (score 0):

On my installation the c:\php\php.ini file was named `php ini`. So phpmyinfo() was not loading it, despite the `PATH` environment variable including `C:\php\`. (Check this in a DOS prompt with `SET PATH`).

So rename it to `php.ini`.

It was difficult to spot in Windows Explorer.